# How to specify default cookie maxAge in Play Framework 2.0?

Tags: playframework-2.0

In Play Framework 1.x one could specify the default cookie max age by setting [`application.session.maxAge`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.3/configuration) in application.conf. The documentation for 2.x does not mention how to override it, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

This [pull request](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/384) tipped me off.

So on line 516 in `Http.scala` session max age is overriden by the configuration variable `session.maxAge` if it exists:

```
    override val maxAge = Play.maybeApplication.flatMap(_.configuration.getInt("session.maxAge")).getOrElse(-1)
```